# Unable to boot into windows directly

Tags: 14.04, windows-10

I am not able to boot directly into windows. I have deleted Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) but the system always boots into grub. How do I remove grub ?

I do not have a windows installer unfortunately.

I am able to boot into windows. But it boots into grub. I have to type
"exit" then it goes into the system configuration and still shows me the option of booting using Windows or Ubuntu.

Please let me know what to do!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Okay I have found the answer. I had to change the acpi=noirq and boot it.

And also changed the grub settings permanently.